# Which libappmenu.so must I edit under GTK 3.0 to remove Eclipse from the HUD blacklist?

Tags: menu, eclipse, hud

Under GTK 2.10.0 one could allow HUD for Eclipse by replacing Eclipse with Xclipse in:

```
/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
```

After doing an update, this file dissapeared from the GTK 2.10 and now I'm guessing I should do the same edit in:

```
/usr/lib/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
```

Only problem is that there is no such file.

I did find a similarly named file:

```
/usr/lib/indicators/7/libappmenu.so
```

But don't know if that is the right place to mess with it.

If anyone has an updated answer for enabling the heads up display (cool menu at the top) for Eclipse under the latest Ubuntu 12.10 will you kindly share it?

Comment: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/eclipse-ide-get-ubuntu-appmenu-and-hud.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too, with gtk3.0 and solved it by editing this file:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
```

in the same way as described for gtk2.0.

My OS is a 64bit OS so i don't know if it's the same for 32bit systems, but hopefully this solution works for you, too.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Just a word of warning for others - on my machine (12.10 64 bit using Eclipse Juno), this change keeps Eclipse from properly refreshing the toolbar icons. Still worth the change for me though.