# How do I make HUD work with Eclipse?

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, hud

I have already tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230564/which-libappmenu-so-must-i-edit-under-gtk-3-0-to-remove-eclipse-from-the-hud-bla), but I still have no entries in HUD regarding Eclipse (Indigo, manually installed).

Is there some way to make HUD work with Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Java applications in general aren't supported by HUD however you can make it work.
All you need to do is remove eclipse from the App menu blacklist according to this blog post:
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/eclipse-ide-get-ubuntu-appmenu-and-hud.html

1) To get Ubuntu AppMenu (global menu) and HUD support for Eclipse IDE, we'll have to whitelist it so we'll hve to modify the GTK2 libappmenu.so file.

To find out the exact GTK2 libappmenu.so path (the path can vary depending on the Ubuntu version you're using and architecture), firstly run the following command:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Once it finishes (there's no output so just wait until it's done), let's find the GTK2 libappmenu.so path by using the following command:

```
locate "gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so"
```

The above command should return the exact GTK2 libappmenu.so path.

2) Let's make a backup before proceeding, so using the path returned by the command above, run the following command:

```
sudo cp /path/to/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so /path/to/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so.bak
```

3) Now let's whielist Eclipse so it supports AppMenu and HUD:

```
sudo sed -i 's/Eclipse/Xclipse/g' /path/to/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
```

And then, restart Eclipse IDE.

**For the last to commands above, remember to use the exact path to the GtK2 libappmenu.so you've found under step 1!**

---

If later on you want to disable appmenu / HUD support for Eclipse IDE (undo the changes), simply follow the first step above to find out the GTK2 libappmenu.so path and restore the backup we've made under step 2 using this command:

```
sudo cp /path/to/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so.bak /path/to/gtk-2.0/2.10.0/menuproxies/libappmenu.so
```

Comment: add steps from link or add important step . only link will not be good way to answer.